# How to auto generate my website sitemap regurlarly (day)?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have developed website in Zend framework, it's like a blog. I'm worried about posting URL links, as they are not being indexed in Google. However, if I generate *sitemap.xml* externally, and upload it, then it is displayed on Google Search. Yet, I think this is not the proper way to submit my sitemap.

So, I'm looking for an automated method to generate a *sitemap.xml* file, i.e., reset a *sitemap.xml* file every day. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: "I generate sitemap.xml externally" - are you using an independent tool, not directly connected with your website?

Comment: Yes,, from http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use cron jobs to do the jobs automatically?

Both cPanel and DirectAdmin have some great GUIs for that purpose.

You can easily set a cron job to automate the execution of *sitemap.xml* generator.

Comment: can you show any demo link....

Comment: Sure. http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm show how you can setup a cron job to automate executing a special php file.

Comment: sorry not cronjob... demo code of auto sitemap.xml generator link

Comment: The way you should generate `sitemap.xml` completely depends on your database schema. Anyway http://www.pontikis.net/blog/creating-dynamic-xml-sitemaps-using-php seams to be helpful.

Comment: now i some what clear about sitemap generation,, thank you @smhnaju

Comment: Happy to hear that. Good luck `:)`